# gcc command not found even though it is there

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, clang

I downloaded Xcode and the command line tools. When I go to the directory "/usr/bin" and enter "ls" in my terminal, I can see gcc listed among the files and directories. However, when I run the command gcc in this directory, I get a message saying: "-bash: gcc: command not found". Why does it say the command can't be found when I can clearly see it listed among the files in my /usr/bin directory?

Comment: is the execute bit set?

Comment: Execute bit? I'm sorry could you explain? And the output to gcc --version I get is: -bash: gcc: command not found.

Comment: Is the item in `/usr/bin` an executable file or perhaps a broken symlink?

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: The output to ls -l /usr/bin/gcc I get is:                         "lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  7 Aug 22 09:35 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.2". Is this incorrect?

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` exist?

Comment: No it does not. There is a gcc-4.0 listed in the directory /usr/bin when I "ls", but when I try calling it, it also tells me that it doesn't exist.

Comment: maybe a help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452239/gcc-command-not-found-even-though-it-is-there/25452337?noredirect=1#comment39714666_25452337

Comment: @Klaus: Your link is to a comment on a deleted answer to *this* question, saying that "OS X 10.9 does not use GCC". I'm afraid it's not helpful.

Comment: @user3772689: Your `/usr/bin` directory is messed up for some reason. `/usr/bin/gcc` should definitely be a symlink to something that actually exists. Have you been messing around with `/usr/bin` yourself? (You'd need root access to do so.)

Comment: You say you *downloaded* Xcode and the command line tools. Did you install them? If so, how? Can you launch the Xcode IDE (the graphical environment)?

Comment: I haven't deleted or added anything to /usr/bin manually, no. I did install them. Xcode installed itself as an application I believe, I can launch the IDE. The command line tools I installed by opening the DMG then launching the installer. The installer ran and ended with a message saying it was successfully installed.

Comment: I tried removing the command line tools and Xcode, then reinstalling them. Now gcc simply doesn't show up in /usr/bin even after I've installed the command line tools. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've added some tags that should draw more attention from people who are more likely to have answers.

Comment: You might have better luck asking on the Apple-specific site: http://apple.stackexchange.com/